# Где поставить ударение в слове "комкующийся"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Где поставить ударение в слове КОМКУЮЩИЙСЯ  (наполнитель)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Справка Грамоты.ру:

[Вопрос № 267062](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=267062)

> Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать про кошачий
>   наполнитель: *комкающийся* или *комкующийся* и почему? Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Логике словообразования соответствует вариант *комкующийся* (т. е.
>   образующий комки), хотя в словарях русского языка такого слова нет.

---

В словарях слова нет, но языковая логика подсказывает: комкУющийся.

См. подсказку:

**[комковаться](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Неожиданно понять причину вопроса.
Есть два глагола: комкать (превращать в комок, мять) и комковаться - приобретать ***комковатость***. То есть переходить из однородной фракции в состояние с множеством комочков или иметь склонность к такому переходу.
С первым все понятно, второй более из профжаргона, не во всех словарях есть, но смысл понятен.

Так вот, первый глагол в полном соответствии с логикой словообразования образует причастие к**о**мкающий(ся), второй - комк**у**ющийся. Понятно, что кошачий лотковый наполнитель связан со вторым глаголом, то есть именно *комк**у**ющийся.*